# Distance Between the Point Masses in a Pair of Coupled Pendula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

Here is an embarrassingly simple problem, which for some reason I can't figure out. You can also find my solution attempt here.

Two point particles of mass $m$, a pair of identical rigid rods of length $a$, and a spring of equilibrium length $b$ and spring constant $k$ are used to construct a coupled pair of pendula as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Suppose that the rods and the spring have negligible mass, the particles are allowed to move in the $x-y$ plane, and at the equilibrium the pendula are in vertical position. Express the distance $d$ between the two particles in terms of the angles $\theta_1$, and $\theta_2$, and show that for small deviations from the equilibrium $|d – a|$ is independent of $a$.

My solution attempt:

\begin{align}
y_s &= a\cos\theta_2 - a\cos\theta_1,\\
 x_s &= b + a\sin\theta_2 - a\sin\theta_1.
\end{align}
So using the Pythagorean theorem $d^2$ can be found as:

$$d^2 = x_s^2 + y_s^2 = 2a^2-2a^2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+b^2+2ab\sin\theta_2-2ab\sin\theta_1-2a^2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2$$

If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are small we can approximate $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ terms by $\theta$ and $1$ and disregard the term containing $\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2$. Hence:

$$d^2 = b^2 +2ab(\theta_2-\theta_1) \implies d = b\sqrt{1+\frac{2a}{b}(\theta_2-\theta_1)}$$

Since $\theta_2-\theta_1$ is small we can Taylor expand the expression as:

$$d \approx b(1+\frac{a}{b}(\theta_2-\theta_1)) = b+a(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

However it is obvious that in this approximation $|d-a| = b+a(\theta_2-\theta_1-1)$ which is not independent of $a$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ir is more meaningful to express $d-b$, since $b$ is the equilibrium distance of the spring. You then  have $d-b = a(\theta_2 - \theta_1)$.

Comment: 1. To be sure I understand: “at the equilibrium the pendula are in vertical position.” Thats cuz the pendula hang from points that are the same distance apart as the natural length if the spring right(?) 2. Need to say how it is being driven, if so. Is this relationship under free motion/oscillation(?) Or you are pulling one rod and the other is free? If the former, then history matters as it is fully dynamic. First step would be find the oscillating equilibrium if there is one and if it’s there. Otherwise need more info

Comment: @ytlu I know. But this is the way the question is asked. It is the first part of one of the questions asked in the qualifier exam of our university a few years ago.

Comment: @AlBrown 1) Yes 2) The oscillation is free

Comment: @AliPedram Obviously, the qualify problem has a typo.

Comment: Are you sure it has a cyclical oscillation? Someone say that? Even if so, then the amplitude may affect the answer as it may be nonlinear. Do you know?

Comment: @ytlu That's also what I thought first. However I looked it up and found the exact same question in another website. So now I think that there might not be a typo. The link is given here:

https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/aeb/aebcfb73-c3bf-4c03-b74c-ff5920b2e510/phpw7zVDl

Comment: @AlBrown What do you mean by cyclical oscillation? For small deviations the motion must be linear.

Comment: If we assume it is linear, then it is one pendulum not two. IF and only if it started out with $v_1=v_2 ~,~x_1=x_2$. Thats also why i said history matters.

Comment: @AliPedram One of them copied the other without careful investigate. And very probably some others will use your post to justify this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The question is flawed. I'm not sure but as @ytlu has suggested in the comments, the author probably wanted to state that $|d-b|$ is independent of $b$.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: In its present form, this answer looks like it ought to be a comment or an edit to the question. If this solves your problem, consider editing your answer to clarify.